# How to download images from a list of URLs in Google Sheets

Tags: image, google-sheets, url, download

I have a list of URLs of images in Google Sheets. Every day, I have to copy these URLs and paste them into a program like **VovSoft Batch URL downloader** to download these pictures in bulk. Is there any way that I can **download these images directly from Google Sheets?**

Answer (score 1):

you can display the images with the formula `=image("HTTP://....")` as a preview.

However if you want to download, you will have to write javascript code in Google App Script module